# How to show that a non-empty $L$ is recognizable iff there exists a total computable function whose range equals $L$

Tags: formal-languages

This almost makes sense to me, but I feel like I'm missing something.

I know that for a decidable language, there must exist some total computable function $f$ that can take in any $x \in \sum^{*}$ and tell us whether or not $x$ is accepted (while my textbook is unclear, I would infer from this that decidable languages and computable functions are equivalent?)

So I can see that $L$ is decidable if and only if some computable function can determine if $x \in L$ or not, which implies the existence of a function $f(x)$ that outputs $x$ if $x \in L$, and nothing otherwise (this makes sense in my head at least...correct me if I'm wrong). How would I use what's given to show that this is true for any recognizable $L$ though? Computable functions have finite steps have to halt, from my understanding, so how that they be used to check if $x$ belongs to a recognizable but undecidable language?

Comment: I believe I mistakenly used the word "total" in my title. I also believe that the Wikipedia page for recursively enumerable sets contains my answer. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Someone already asked this question, but I can't find the question right now.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. If $L$ is recognized by some Turing machine $T$, then consider a Turing machine that on input $(x,n)$, runs $T$ on $x$ for $n$ steps and outputs $x$ if $T$ halts within $n$ steps.
2. If $L$ is enumerated by some Turing machine $T$, then given $x$, accept it if it appears in the list generated by $T$.

Comment: Maybe I'm just getting tired, but I'm not quite sure what you're getting at in your first hint? You can keep incrementing $n$ to see if $x$ is ever accepted, but if $X \notin L$, it still wouldn't halt, if I'm thinking about this correctly.

Comment: Also, I rescind my other comment. I THINK I'm supposed to be assuming $f$ is a total computable function (but partial computable functions are the ranges of certain total computable functions, are they not?)

Comment: Here are my definitions. $L$ is *recognizable* if there's a Turing machine that on input $x$ halts iff $x \in L$. $L$ is *enumerable* if there is a *total* Turing machine $T$ whose range is $L$.